# Extract value from Series

Tags: pandas

I want to add

I get all values from column:

```
from collections import Counter
coun_ = set(train_df['time1'].dt.hour)
```

Then I add new columns to data frame and fill there default values:

```
for i in coun_:
    train_df['hour'+str(i)] = 0
```

Now I want to get hour from `time1` and set `1` to right column. Forexample, if `time1` equals 10 then I put 1 to `hour10`. I do several ways without success, one of them.

```
for hour in [train_df]:
    hour['hour' + hour['time1'].dt.hour.to_string()] = 1
```

The question is how I can extract only value from Series and concat it?

Comment: Can you add some data sample, 3 4 values of `train_df['time1']` and expected output?

Comment: @jezrael `train_df['time1'][:3]` returns session_id
1   2014-02-20 10:02:45
2   2014-02-22 11:19:50
3   2013-12-16 16:40:17

Comment: Thank you, so my solution working? Or what is expected output?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain how can I write this values in data frame?

Comment: I ask because first rule in pandas is [dont loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) adn append to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(train_df['time1'].dt.hour).add_prefix('hour'))
```

Comment: I do this `one_hot = pd.get_dummies(train_df['time1'].dt.hour)
train_df = train_df.join(one_hot)` Maybe you know to set custom names for new columns?